# Is there a way to use the Amazon .NET AWS SDK's AmazonS3 client on 'publicly readable buckets' without specifying AWS credentials?

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-s3, amazon-web-services

I would like to use Amazon's .NET SDK for accessing a publicly readable bucket, but the `AWSClientFactory.CreateAmazonS3Client` method for creating an `AmazonS3` forces you to input your AwsAccessKey and AwsSecretAccessKey.

I do not want to include these in my client-side application, but I still want to use the SDK provided by Amazon to access these publicly readable objects on S3.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I also asked this question on the AWS forum and an official Amazon employee responded:

> As of the 1.3.8.0 release of the SDK you can pass null for the access
>   and secret key and the SDK will skip the signing process and try the
>   operations like GetObject as a public operation.
>
> Norm

It's worth noting that at the time of writting, the current Amazon .NET SDK is at version '1.3.14', so passing null for the credentials is currently possible.