# using php to upload to Amazon S3 without access & secret key

Tags: php, amazon-s3

Using PHP I want to upload some files to amazon s3 public bucket. But I don't want to use access key and secret key in my code. Because when I searched and found that using keyword "null" will solve the case. In PHP we use '' as null, but doesn't have luck. Below is my code

```
<?php

if (!class_exists('s3'))require_once('s3.php');
//AWS access info
if (!defined('awsAccessKey')) define('awsAccessKey', 'null');
if (!defined('awsSecretKey')) define('awsSecretKey', 'null');
//instantiate the class
$s3 = new S3(awsAccessKey, awsSecretKey);
$s3->putBucket("bucket name", S3::ACL_PUBLIC_READ_WRITE);

//move the file
if ($s3->putObjectFile("your file name in the server with path", "bucket name", "fine name in s3 server",S3::ACL_PUBLIC_READ_WRITE)){

//s3 upload success

}
```

Comment: see here... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9278437/uploading-to-amazon-s3-without-access-secret-key

Comment: Than try like `new S3(null,null);`, currently it must be taking null as a string.

Comment: sorry gives this error  [AccessDenied] Anonymous access is forbidden for this operation