# How to upload a file to AWS S3 without access key & secret key

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

Before I begin, I have already read [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9278437/uploading-to-amazon-s3-without-access-secret-key) related to same question. However the SDK version in that post is old.
As per [AWS nugetpage](http://www.nuget.org/profiles/awsdotnet) there is new version 3 is available which has separate packages for each service.

> The new version 3 of the AWS SDK for .NET uses separate packages for
>   each service. For example Amazon S3 is in the AWSSDK.S3 package,
>   Amazon SQS is in AWSSDK.SQS and Amazon DynamnoDB is in
>   AWSSDK.DynamoDBv2.

So i have installed `AWSSDK.S3` package from nuget which also installs dependency `AWSSDK.Core`. 
The bucket im using is restricted using IP, so machine where im executing code has full access to the bucket.

Below is my code to upload a file to S3.  However im getting exception when i create new instance of `AmazonS3Client` using `new AmazonS3Client(RegionEndpoint.USWest2);`

again note that i am getting exception is while creating the instance not while uploading the file.

```
 var s3Client = new AmazonS3Client(RegionEndpoint.USWest2);  //exception at this line

 var bucketName = "mybucketname";
  PutObjectRequest putRequest1 = new PutObjectRequest
  {
                BucketName = bucketName,
                Key = "MyKey/test1.pdf",
                FilePath = filePath
  };

  PutObjectResponse response1 = s3Client.PutObject(putRequest1);
```

However i get exception

> [15:57:43 ERR] Unhandled exception
>   Amazon.Runtime.AmazonServiceException: Unable to find credentials
>
> Exception 1 of 5: System.InvalidOperationException: The
>   app.config/web.config files for the application did not contain
>   credential information    at
>   Amazon.Runtime.AppConfigAWSCredentials..ctor() in
>   E:\JenkinsWorkspaces\v3-stage-release\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Core\Amazon.Runtime\AWSCredentials.cs:line
>   977    at
>   Amazon.Runtime.FallbackCredentialsFactory.<>c.b__6_0() in
>   E:\JenkinsWorkspaces\v3-stage-release\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Core\Amazon.Runtime\AWSCredentials.cs:line
>   2098    at
>   Amazon.Runtime.FallbackCredentialsFactory.GetCredentials(Boolean
>   fallbackToAnonymous) in
>   E:\JenkinsWorkspaces\v3-stage-release\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Core\Amazon.Runtime\AWSCredentials.cs
>
> Exception 2 of 5: System.ArgumentException: App.config does not
>   contain credentials information. Either add the AWSAccessKey and
>   AWSSecretKey properties or the AWSProfileName property.    at
>   Amazon.Runtime.StoredProfileAWSCredentials..ctor(String profileName,
>   String profilesLocation) in
>   E:\JenkinsWorkspaces\v3-stage-release\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Core\Amazon.Runtime\AWSCreden
>   at Amazon.Runtime.FallbackCredentialsFactory.<>c.b__6_1() in
>   E:\JenkinsWorkspaces\v3-stage-release\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Core\Amazon.Runtime\AWSCredentials.cs:line
>   2099    at
>   Amazon.Runtime.FallbackCredentialsFactory.GetCredentials(Boolean
>   fallbackToAnonymous) in
>   E:\JenkinsWorkspaces\v3-stage-release\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Core\Amazon.Runtime\AWSCredentials.cs
>
> Exception 3 of 5: System.ArgumentException: Profile '' was not found
>   or could not be loaded from the SDK credential store. Verify that the
>   profile name and data are correct.    at
>   Amazon.Runtime.StoredProfileFederatedCredentials..ctor(String
>   profileName, String profilesLocation, WebProxy proxySettings) in
>   E:\JenkinsWorkspaces\v3-stage-release\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src    at
>   Amazon.Runtime.FallbackCredentialsFactory.<>c.b__6_2() in
>   E:\JenkinsWorkspaces\v3-stage-release\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Core\Amazon.Runtime\AWSCredentials.cs:line
>   2101    at
>   Amazon.Runtime.FallbackCredentialsFactory.GetCredentials(Boolean
>   fallbackToAnonymous) in
>   E:\JenkinsWorkspaces\v3-stage-release\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Core\Amazon.Runtime\AWSCredentials.cs
>
> Exception 4 of 5: System.InvalidOperationException: The environment
>   variables AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID/AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY/AWS_SESSION_TOKEN
>   were not set with AWS credentials.    at
>   Amazon.Runtime.EnvironmentVariablesAWSCredentials.FetchAWSCredentials()
>   in
>   E:\JenkinsWorkspaces\v3-stage-release\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Core\Amazon.Runtime\AWSCredentials.cs:line
>   856    at Amazon.Runtime.EnvironmentVariablesAWSCredentials..ctor() in
>   E:\JenkinsWorkspaces\v3-stage-release\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Core\Amazon.Runtime\AWSCredentials.cs:line
>   836    at
>   Amazon.Runtime.FallbackCredentialsFactory.<>c.b__6_3() in
>   E:\JenkinsWorkspaces\v3-stage-release\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Core\Amazon.Runtime\AWSCredentials.cs:line
>   2102    at
>   Amazon.Runtime.FallbackCredentialsFactory.GetCredentials(Boolean
>   fallbackToAnonymous) in
>   E:\JenkinsWorkspaces\v3-stage-release\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Core\Amazon.Runtime\AWSCredentials.cs
>
> Exception 5 of 5: Amazon.Runtime.AmazonServiceException: Unable to
>   reach credentials server    at
>   Amazon.Runtime.URIBasedRefreshingCredentialHelper.GetContents(Uri uri)
>   in
>   E:\JenkinsWorkspaces\v3-stage-release\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Core\Amazon.Runtime\AWSCredentials.cs:line
>   1194    at
>   Amazon.Runtime.InstanceProfileAWSCredentials.d__10.MoveNext()
>   in
>   E:\JenkinsWorkspaces\v3-stage-release\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Core\Amazon.Runtime\AWSCredentials.cs:line
>   at Amazon.Runtime.InstanceProfileAWSCredentials.GetFirstRole() in
>   E:\JenkinsWorkspaces\v3-stage-release\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Core\Amazon.Runtime\AWSCredentials.cs:line
>   1422    at
>   Amazon.Runtime.FallbackCredentialsFactory.ECSEC2CredentialsWrapper()
>   in
>   E:\JenkinsWorkspaces\v3-stage-release\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Core\Amazon.Runtime\AWSCredentials.cs:line
>   2129    at
>   Amazon.Runtime.FallbackCredentialsFactory.GetCredentials(Boolean
>   fallbackToAnonymous) in
>   E:\JenkinsWorkspaces\v3-stage-release\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Core\Amazon.Runtime\AWSCredentials.cs
>
> at Amazon.Runtime.FallbackCredentialsFactory.GetCredentials(Boolean
>   fallbackToAnonymous) in
>   E:\JenkinsWorkspaces\v3-stage-release\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Core\Amazon.Runtime\AWSCredentials.cs    at Amazon.Runtime.FallbackCredentialsFactory.GetCredentials() in
>   E:\JenkinsWorkspaces\v3-stage-release\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Core\Amazon.Runtime\AWSCredentials.cs:line
>   2136    at Amazon.S3.AmazonS3Client..ctor(RegionEndpoint region) in
>   E:\JenkinsWorkspaces\v3-stage-release\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Services\S3\Generated_bcl45\AmazonS3Client.cs:line
>   80    at Utility.Program.Dowork() in
>   C:\repos\poc\Utility\Utility\Program.cs:line 133    at
>   Utility.Program.Main(String[] args) in
>   C:\repos\poc\Utility\Utility\Program.cs:line 23

Answer (score 3):

The behavior specified in the link for the much older SDK is still valid. If you configure the `AmazonS3Client` with `null` values for the access key and secret, the client will operate in anonymous mode.

This is undocumented in the .NET documentation for the SDK, but is documented in the [S3 Developer Guide's .NET section](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/AuthUsingAcctOrUserCredDotNet.html).

> **Note**
>
> You can create the `AmazonS3Client` client without providing your security credentials. Requests sent using this client are anonymous requests, without a signature. Amazon S3 returns an error if you send anonymous requests for a resource that is not publicly available.

You'll likely want to use a constructor like the one that [takes a key, secret, and region](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/v3/apidocs/Index.html).

```
// passing null for the key and secret will make the client generate anonymous requests
var client = new AmazonS3Client(null, null, RegionEndpoint.USWest2);

// do things with the client
```

Answer (score 2):

To get the access to any bucket, you would require its Access and Secret keys, as you are using SDK here " var s3Client = new AmazonS3Client(RegionEndpoint.USWest2);". You only need to provide the credentials in your config file, the SDK will automatically fetch the credentials from there.

Answer (score 0):

For that to work you instance has to have an IAM role that has permission to put an object to the bucket.

According to the [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/v3/apidocs/items/S3/TS3S3Client.html):

> Constructs AmazonS3Client with the credentials loaded from the
>   application's default configuration, and if unsuccessful **from the
>   Instance Profile** service on an EC2 instance.

Read more about instance profiles at http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_use_switch-role-ec2_instance-profiles.html